# is there a way to access desktop application windows using chrome extension? [chrome.desktopcapture.choosedesktopmedia]

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screen-capture

Current google chrome API is serving only to access browser windows and tabs, and for the desktop app windows, there is an api `chrome.desktopcapture.choosedesktopmedia ['Window']`, which prompts the user to choose or select one from a list.

[image]

Is there a way to bypass the user prompt for choosing desktop media, and handle through code to get all desktop app windows as objects?

Comment: Would YOU want any arbitrary extension to be able to screenshot any of your apps without explicitly asking for it? This seems like there’s a very, **very** good reason why this isn’t possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is something you will ever be able to use -- it is SUPPOSED to have a prompt according to the documentation.  It would be dangerous to provide that without warning the user since it isn't part of Chrome, but an extension, which is able to capture ANYTHING every time it is used.

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/#type-DesktopCaptureSourceType

[image: This permission triggers a warning. - part of Documentation on Desktop Window capturing in Chrome API]